# Execute script to initialize environment vars prior to using an external build system (Makefile) in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

I am building a Makefile based project using Xcode4. How do I tell xcode to run a script that initializes environment variables for Intel's CC/fortran compiler prior to the Makefile being run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead created a shell script that calls the Intel init scripts and then executes /usr/bin/make.